# Events thunderbolt for form itself in the properties window

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, properties, ide

Properties window asp.net:  Just like other controls have that thunderbolt icon, when you select the entire form itself, I don't see a thunderbolt for the page level events.

When you double click on the form, Load is created for you.
But there are other page level events, and I expected to see them and define them, through properties window.

But for the form itself, there is none.  See screenshot.

Is this by design?  Or am I experiencing an anomaly?

My guess is that maybe the event recognized by the web page through the name of the method itself  (Like page load is always Page_Load, etc.)
[Click here for screenshot...No Thunderbolt:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nhbH.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think this is by design.  Only certain event names are recognized.

You can type this in, and it will recognize these event names and do accordingly:

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ Response.Write("Page_PreInit" + "<br/>"); }

protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ Response.Write("Page_Init" + "<br/>"); }

protected void Page_InitComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ Response.Write("Page_InitComplete" + "<br/>"); }

protected void Page_PreLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ Response.Write("Page_PreLoad" + "<br/>"); }

protected void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ Response.Write("Page_LoadComplete" + "<br/>"); }

protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ Response.Write("Page_PreRender" + "<br/>"); }

protected void Page_PreRenderComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ Response.Write("Page_PreRenderComplete" + "<br/>"); }

protected void Page_Unload(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
   //Response.Write("Page_Unload" + "<br/>"); 
}
```